# To the lonely I call

Tags: riddle

> I climb only to fall,
>
> and people often avoid me.
>
> They may not care at all,
>
> but they all know that they need me.
>
> I can fill the streets and invade your house,
>
> but most of the time I fall under.
>
> Leave you feeling unaroused,
>
> and even make you wonder.

**Who or What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm thinking **water**

I climb only to fall

> Evaporate, and fall as rain

and people often avoid me

> Not in my case, I love when rain hits my face

They may not care at all, but they all know that they need me.

> We take it for granted sometimes

I can fill the streets and invade your house, but most of the time I fall under.

> That's what rain does, but mostly it gets drained

Leave you feeling unaroused, and even make you wonder.

> Sadness and contemplation

Comment: Oh! OK  i'm new here

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE :)

Please write some explanation why your answer makes sense.

Comment: That username is the best xD

Answer (score 3):

> The rain.

Explanation is pretty straightforward.

I climb only to fall,
and people often avoid me.

> Water evaporates and gets into the clouds only to come back down as rain.

They may not care at all,
but they all know that they need me.

> You don't really think about water's circuit, but you need the rain for crops and chill outs.

I can fill the streets and invade your house,
but most of the time I fall under.

> Heavy raining can cause flooding, but normally it just gets into the ground.

Leave you feeling unaroused,
and even make you wonder.

> Unaroused as in "not wet"? :) Make you wonder - rain makes us melancholic.

Comment: I think this one is better then the chosen answer, because all lines are about your answer in stead of the chosen answer! Besides that, you answer was posted earlier. (And its annoying to not spoil anything :P )

Comment: @FearsomeStatue Thanks, but the other one has received more votes, so...

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Fire

I climb only to fall,

> Fire flames "dance" up and down (climbing and falling constantly)

and people often avoid me.

> They do in order not to get burned

They may not care at all,

> It is abundant

but they all know that they need me.

> Fire is indeed very important thing for human beings

I can fill the streets and invade your house,

> A great fire can do this. Such an "invasion" would be pretty devastating.

but most of the time I fall under.

> Most of the time fire is placed under the thing you want to heat up.

Leave you feeling unaroused,

> When your inner fire leaves you, you become "unaroused"

and even make you wonder.

> People often stare at the flames and wonder...

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Sun?

---

I climb only to fall,

> Sun climbs to its zenith, then falls to horizon.

and people often avoid me.

> People try to escape sunburn or wear sunglasses.

They may not care at all,

> People usually don't think about nature of Sun.

but they all know that they need me.

> Without the Sun Earth would be a cold empty planet.

I can fill the streets and invade your house,

> Sunlight may pass behind closed doors and windows.

but most of the time I fall under.

> Daytime is not always long, and houses often hide sun before the actual sunset.

Leave you feeling unaroused,

> May mean cloudy and gloomy days, when sun actually gives light but cannot break through skies.

and even make you wonder.

> May refer to beautiful sunsets and sunrises.

Comment: This is what I thought :P

Answer (score 1):

You could be

> Summer

I climb only to fall,

> Summer is only present before **fall** (autumn) comes in

and people often avoid me.

> People like to avoid extensive heat in summer (i.e. by using air conditioning) (thanks to mr23ceec)

They may not care at all,

> Some people are neutral to summer

but they all know that they need me.

> Season cycle is necessary for earth to provide the plants etc. Summer is crucial to the crops etc.

I can fill the streets and invade your house,

> Summer fills the streets and your house with hot air

but most of the time I fall under.

> 3/4 of the year it waits to come back

Leave you feeling unaroused, and even make you wonder.

> High temperatures make people more lazy and "unaroused" and thinking of not really important things and "wonder"

Comment: I think you meant summer. Fall comes *before* winter. Of all the seasons, winter is least useful for crops. Summer fits all the rest of your statements too, except for the second one, which can be fixed by saying "air conditioned" rather than "warmer".

Comment: Wow, I had to be really tired while writing this. Of course fall is not after winter :D

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Water.
>  I know this answer has already been given, but giving some different and hopefully more complete reasoning here.

To the lonely I call (the title)

> People often suicide by drowning themselves and/or jumping off bridges into water.

I climb only to fall,

> The water cycle; evaporating into the clouds, only to fall as rain - and continue falling by running downhill.

and people often avoid me.

> People generally avoid puddles, avoid going out in rain, and go around lakes and ponds or over rivers and streams - not through them.

They may not care at all,
but they all know that they need me.

> Many people aren't particularly concerned about their water intake, but we all know we need water to live.

I can fill the streets and invade your house,

> Flooding does these, of course.

but most of the time I fall under.

> Typically, rainwater falls under streets through storm drains, and wastewater falls underground and under streets through sewer systems; fresh water comes to our homes etc. through underground pipes, and more generally, natural water is below ground in aquifers.

Leave you feeling unaroused,

> Cold showers!

and even make you wonder.

> Rainbows!

Those last two, which I don't think anyone alluded to, inspired this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one suggested:

> The moon

I climb only to fall,

> Rising and setting

and people often avoid me.

> Going out at night

They may not care at all,

> Night-people

but they all know that they need me.

> Seeing at night?

I can fill the streets and invade your house,

> Light from the moon

but most of the time I fall under.

> more so in the summer

Leave you feeling unaroused,

> I'll bet the moon is a god of virility/randy-ness or something somewhere

and even make you wonder.

> "What's out there?"

Answer (score -1):

Could you be

> Alcohol

To the lonely I call

> Stereotypically people drunk after a break up or when lonely

I climb only to fall

> Alcohol is produced through an exothermic reaction, which means it gains a lot of energy, and then lets it all out.

And people often avoid me.

> People avoid alcohol as they believe it is bad (it kinda is)

They may not care at all

> Some people drink a lot and don't care for their health in doing so

but they all know that they need me

> Maybe a stretch bu alcohol is a great sanitiser and can keep you from getting bacteria in your body

I can fill the streets and invade your house

> Drunk people on the street, bottles in the street, bard lining streets and also people drinking at home

but most of the time I fall under

> Alcohol makes people throw up, which typically will fall under their feet

Leave you feeling unaroused, and even make you wonder

> Drinking often makes people tired, and also can make people say very strange things - or making them wonder strange things